# Bash, Escaping quotes in command construction,

Tags: string, bash

I have an array of numbers - `sipPeers`.

I want to iterate trough that array and pass each value into the command

`asterisk -rx "sip show peer 1234"` - where 1234 is obviously an extension.

The output of `sip show peer` is piped and manipulated twice to output one value which I want to store in a second array `sipUserAgent`.

```
temp="asterisk -rx \"sip show peer "${sipPeers[q]}"\" | grep Useragent |  awk \'{print$3}\'" #(1)
echo $temp #(2)
sipUserAgent[q]=$($temp) #(3)
```

The output of one iteration yields the constructed command as a string (2) and the tries to execute it (3):

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peer 564" | grep Useragent | awk '{print }'
No such command '"sip' (type 'core show help sip' for other possible commands)
```

If I copy and paste the echo'd command it runs, but when the script executes I get that error. Somewhere the `"` character changes meaning when the scipt executes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st problem

In the step (1) you write: `awk \'{print$3}\'`

In the output of (2) you receive: `awk '{print }'`

The problem is an missed escape of `$3`

Try is again with `awk \'{print\$3}\'` in (1)

### 2nd problem

`sipUserAgent[q]=$($temp)` tries to invoke a command `asterisk_-rx...`

This is surely not what you want. 
The solution is to use `eval` - see `help eval` for more informations.

#### example

```
cmd="echo TEST"
$(${cmd})
```

gives:

> TEST: command not found

```
cmd="echo TEST"
eval ${cmd}
```

gives:

> TEST

### Note about code style

If possible it is better to avoid complex command creation and execution via `eval`.
Better is to write more simple code, if applicable.
So you should use (as also mentioned by Gordon Davisson in another answer):

```
sipUserAgent[q]=$(asterisk -rx "sip show peer ${sipPeers[q]}" \
 | grep Useragent \
 |  awk '{print $3}' \
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with the fixed awk command, but the problem is earlier in command (2). Asterisk is passed the double quotes, instead of just the value quoted. Te error I get is "No such command '"sip'". the double quotes is passed in with the command sip.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, that has sorted out my problem. I will try every solution posted here and report back, but for now the eval approach worked. SipUserAgent[q]=$(eval $temp)

Comment: I have marked this one as correct as I learnt more from it, but in principle I think Gordon's answer is fundamentally the better path to take next time. :) Thanks all!

Comment: @Rudolf: I put your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to store the command in a variable before executing it. There are all sorts of problems with doing this, and you're running into several of them (see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). Just put the pipeline directly inside `$( ... )` where it belongs:

```
sipUserAgent[q]=$(asterisk -rx "sip show peer ${sipPeers[q]}" | grep Useragent |  awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to escape quotes during command substitution, but a workaround is to use `eval`. See the following example:

```
$ cat test.sh 
echo "$1"
$ temp="./test.sh \"2 34 434\" "
$ echo "$temp"
./test.sh "2 34 434"
$ result=$(eval $temp)
$ echo "$result"
2 34 434
$ result=$($temp)
$ echo "$result"
"2
```

Note that using `eval` is generally considered bad practice in most situations, if you can avoid it.